# Is Scala's match an expression or not?

Tags: scala, syntax

I'm confused with Scala's syntax again. I expected this to work just fine:

```
// VERSION 1
def isInteractionKnown(service: Service, serviceId: String) = service match {
    case TwitterService =>
        twitterInteractions.findUuidByTweetId(serviceId.toLong)
    case FacebookService =>
        facebookInteractions.findUuidByServiceId(serviceId)
}.isDefined
```

*NOTE*: Both `findUuidByTweetId` and `findUuidByServiceId` return an `Option[UUID]`

`scalac` tells me:

```
error: ';' expected but '.' found.
}.isDefined
```

When I let my IDE (IDEA) reformat the code, `.isDefined` part ends up on a line of it's own. It's as if `match` isn't an expression. But in my mind, what I did was functionally equivalent to:

```
// VERSION 2
def isInteractionKnown(service: Service, serviceId: String) = {
    val a = service match {
        case TwitterService =>
            twitterInteractions.findUuidByTweetId(serviceId.toLong)
        case FacebookService =>
            facebookInteractions.findUuidByServiceId(serviceId)
    }

    a.isDefined
}
```

which parses and does exactly what I want. Why is the first syntax not accepted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is an expression. Not all expressions are equal, though; according to the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), Chapter 6, "Expressions", the receiver of a method invocation can only come from a (syntactical) subset of all expressions (`SimpleExpr` in the grammar), and `match` expressions are not in that subset (neither are `if` expressions, for instance).

As a result, you need to put parentheses around them:

```
(service match {
  case => ...
  ...
}).isDefined
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529668/scala-can-you-use-foo-match-bar-in-an-expression-without-parentheses) has some more answers.

(Edited to incorporate some comments.)

Comment: But why? If match is an expression, why do I need to turn it into another expression?

Comment: Because it is not a simple expression. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529668/scala-can-you-use-foo-match-bar-in-an-expression-without-parentheses) for more.

Comment: `foo bar {baz}.quux` apparently parses to `foo bar ({baz}.quux)`, rather than `(foo bar {baz}).quux`

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @agilesteel. Greatly appreciated!