# Scala precedence of implied dots and parentheses

Tags: scala, operator-precedence

How is the following "parenthesized"?

```
val words = List("foo", "bar", "baz")
val phrase = "These are upper case: " + words map { _.toUpperCase } mkString ", "
```

Is it the same as

```
val words = List("foo", "bar", "baz")
val phrase = "These are upper case: " + words.map(_.toUpperCase).mkString(", ")
```

In other words, do implied dots (".") and parentheses have the same precedence as the real ones?

Is the first version the same as

```
val words = List("foo", "bar", "baz")
val phrase =
  "These are upper case: " + (words map { _.toUpperCase } mkString ", ")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators starting with letters have the lowest precedence. `+` has low precedence but higher than `map` or `mkString`. So

```
"These are upper case: " + words map { _.toUpperCase } mkString ", "
```

should be parsed as:

```
(("These are upper case: " + words).map{ _.toUpperCase }).mkString(", ")
```

Think of it as:

```
v1 + v2 map v3 mkString v4
((v1 + v2) map v3) mkString v4
```

See my other answer for more info: [When to use parenthesis in Scala infix notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592642/when-to-use-parenthesis-in-scala-infix-notation/5597154#5597154)

Comment: Technically speaking, assignment operators have even lower precedence so it's often used by DSLs.