# Scala - Why does dotless not apply to this case

Tags: scala

I'm parsing some XML, and I'm chaining calls without a dot. All of these methods take no parameters (except `\\`, which takes one), so it should be fairly possible to chain them without a dot, right?

This is the code that does not work:

`val angle = filteredContextAttributes.head \\ "contextValue" text toDouble`

The error is: `not found: value toDouble`

However, it does work like this:

`(filteredContextAttributes.head \\ "contextValue" text) toDouble`

`text` returns only a `String` and does not take parameters, and I don't see any other parameters needed in `\\` to cause an issue.

What am I missing? I don't want to hack it out, but to understand what' the problem.

And also I can't use `head` without the dot. When removing the dot it says: `Cannot resolve symbol head`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `text` is a **postfix** notation - this means a method follows the object *and* takes no parameters. The trick with postfix is that it can only appear at the **end** expression. That's why when you add parenthesis it works (the expression is then bounded by the parenthesis and you get two postfix notations, one ending with **text** and the second one ending with **toDouble**). In your example that's not the case as you are trying to call a method further in the chain.

That's also the reason why you need to do `filteredContextAttributes.head` and not `filteredContextAttributes head`. I'm sure if you do `(filteredContextAttributes head)` it will work as again the postfix notation will be at the end of the expression!

There are also **prefix** and **infix** notations in Scala and I urge you to read about them to get a hang of when you can skip `.` and `()` (for instance why you need `()` when using the `map` method etc.).

Comment: Just at the time you posted the answer I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f . Somehow I feel it should be indexed better... Nevertheless, thank you very much!

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic oh that's an amazing answer, people definitely should read it :-)

Answer (score 2):

To add on what @Mateusz already answered, this is the because of mixing postfix notation and [arity-0 suffix notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix-notation).

There's also a great write up in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5597154/125901

You can even see a warning on your shorter example:

```
scala> filteredContextAttributes.head \\ "contextValue" text
<console>:10: warning: postfix operator text should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scala docs for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
```

Which is a pretty subtle hint that this isn't the best construct style-wise.  So, if you aren't specifically working in a DSL, then you should prefer adding in explicit dots and parenthesis, especially when mixing infix, postfix and/or suffix notations.

For example, you can prefer `doc \\ "child"` over `doc.\\("child")`, but once you step outside the DSL--in this example when you get your `NodeSeq`--prefer adding in perens.

Comment: That's strange, I have not seen that warning.

Comment: You only see it when you use the `-feature` scalac flag.  So perhaps *very* subtle would be a better term.