# One parameter function

Tags: scala

If I remove the parentheses from below to read `printFn hc` I get an error. I thought in Scala one parameter functions don't need the parens?

```
case class HelloClass(arg1:String)


object HelloWorld extends App {
  var hc = HelloClass("Hello World")
  printFn(hc)

  def printFn(a1:HelloClass) : Unit = {
    println(a1 arg1) /* or a1.arg1 */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mixed it up with the [infix method notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html). In Scala you can write either `obj.method(argument)` or `obj method argument`.

To apply this to your example, you need the "`obj`" part of the expression, so if you want to avoid parenthesis, you can write

```
this printFn hc
```

See also ["When to use parenthesis in Scala infix notation"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5592642/736957).

Answer (score 1):

I Would like to add something about *postfix* as another answer covered about *infix*.Copied from  [Programming Scala](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033073.do)

> So, 1 + 2 is the same as 1.+(2), because of the “infix” notation where
>   we can drop the period and parentheses for single-argument methods.1
>   Similarly, a method with no arguments can be invoked without the
>   period. This is called “postfix” notation. However, use of this
>   postfix convention can sometimes be confusing, so Scala 2.10 made it
>   an optional feature.

**Example for Postfix**

```
1 toString
```

**Example for Infix**

```
private def testMethod(arg1: String): String = {
    arg1
  }
//this specifies current instance
println(this testMethod "Hello Scala")
```